# Unable to load udev rules file

Tags: 20.04, udev, tpm

After modifying `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-tpm.rules` file, am trying to reload using below commands

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger
```

But getting error as below:

```
edge@edge:~$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
Failed to wait for daemon to reply: Connection timed out
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Could you share from where you get `99-tpm.rules` and its current contents? It could just wrong syntax